# int b=0,a=1;b= ++a + ++a; what is the value of b? what is the calculation for it?

Tags: c, prefix

```
int main()
{
    int b=0,a=1;//initialize a and b
    b=++a + ++a;// calculate assign the value of b
    print f("%d",b);
    return 0;
}
```

1. what is the value of b?
2. and what is the calculation for it?

Comment: This question and the famous *== vs equals in Java* are the most two asked question on earth.

Comment: `undefined behaviour` for the win

Comment: I wonder why question papers have these type of questions ?

Comment: Maybe SO should automagically prevent posting of questions containing `++a + ++a` and such.

Answer (score 2):

This is [Undefined Behaviour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).Lack of [sequence point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point).

For more info have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/859433/which-issues-have-you-encountered-due-to-sequence-points-in-c-and-c) and [output-of-multiple-post-and-pre-increments-in-one-statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3812850/output-of-multiple-post-and-pre-increments-in-one-statement).

Answer (score 1):

It would seem that having a sequence point is immaterial in the expression `b=++a + ++a;`

That is, whether the first `++a` is evaluated first or the second `++a` is evaluated first in either case `a` is incremented twice and then the `+` operator takes effect, so the eventual equation is either `b = 2 + 3;` or `b = 3 + 2` thus b = 5.

When I get home I will try this on with my C compiler.

Blastfurnace's comment about both being evaluated before the `+` operator takes effect is correct, and now that I think about it, obvious.

That is, `+` is lower in precedence than `++a`.  It could be argued that this statement is NOT ambiguous in that switching the order of evaluation (R to L or L to R, both with respect to precedence) results in the same answer.

No one will claim this is well written code, interesting on several points for a discussion, but not something that should be endorsed.

Comment: ...or both side are evaluated before the addition and the result is `3 + 3`. Either way this code is awful and there is no point trying to reason about it.

Comment: in my c compiler the value of b is showing is 6. here a single memory named "a" is shared for both times. for first ++a the vale of a = 2 and for 2nd ++a ,a=3 then b=3+3=6.

Comment: @Arijit, I agree, after actually trying it.